# How to add two column values to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can I add two column value to a list, the two column are in different table. email is in tbl_user table and groupname is in tbl_group table. And I want to use the prefix text for both the email and group name for the auto complete text box. Now with the query I am able to add the email id to the list and when I type arr then email id starting with arr are displayed how can I do it for both groupname and emailID

```
  public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
           MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();


    string textforlist = "SELECT tbl_user.Email from tbl_user WHERE tbl_user.OrganisationID = '1' AND UserActive='Yes'AND tbl_User.Email like '" + prefixText + "%'";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new MySqlParameter("@OrganisationID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    param[0].Value = count;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganisationID", count);
    using (DataServer server = new DataServer())
    {

        ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, textforlist, param);

    }
    string textforlist1 = "SELECT tbl_group.GroupName from tbl_group WHERE tbl_group.OrganisationID = '1' AND GroupActive='Yes'AND tbl_group.GroupName like '" + prefixText + "%'";
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    using (DataServer server = new DataServer())
    {

        ds1 = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, textforlist1, param);

    }
    List<string> cityList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        cityList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        cityList.Add(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }
    return cityList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: How to make sure it returns the array even if 1 value is null

Comment: Just use two `for` loops

Comment: I want to add int newOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uOrgID"].ToString()); get this value and add this to param value for @OrganisationID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the other column value as well? Maybe I don't understand the question correctly but this should be straightforward - your table has two columns, `Email` is the first and `GroupName` the second:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
   cityList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
   cityList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
```

You can modify your sql query to restrict the returned group names similar to how you currently do it for Email - you really should use SQL parameters for this though, otherwise you are open for SQL injection attacks.

**Edit:**

With your updated code you should use two for loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cityList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
}

for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cityList.Add(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: How to add tbl_group.GroupName,  like I do for email tbl_User.Email like '" + prefixText + "%'";

Comment: You could add another `Where` condition in your SQL: `AND tbl_group.GroupName like '" + prefixText + "%'"`

Comment: @Mark: I see now - really your group name and email queries should be independent. Personally in this case I would do two separate SQL queries.

Comment: I am now doing a separate query and adding it to the list, for example if there is email id like email@abc.com and group name as email then both are displayed. If there are no group called email then the email id is not displayed. Even if there is not groupname starting with ema I should display the emailid starting with ema. How to do that

Comment: Mark: That is because your query is using an inner join that requires a match on both tables. You could either do an outer join and handle the null columns or do two separate queries, with two ExecuteQuery calls

Comment: I am using two dataset to get the list 
            cityList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
            cityList.Add(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());   How to make sure it returns the array even if 1 value is null

Comment: Do you know how I can use session inside the method?

Answer (score 0):

In case your table column selection increase then you will be requiring List filled with Custom objects. To achieve you must create a custom object class first.